# Trying to access subclass methods

Tags: java, netbeans, instanceof

So i have an array called roster filled with both Pitchers and Batters and Players( the Player is the super-class of both pitchers and batters)

> private Player[] roster;
>
> roster[i] = new Pitcher();

How i would i access methods in the pitcher? For example:

> ```
> public double calculateTeamERA()
> {
>     double ERA = 0;
>     for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
>     {
>         if(roster[i] instanceof Pitcher)
>         {
>             ERA+= roster[i].calculateERA();
>         }      
>     }
>     return ERA;
> }
> ```

So i have a calculate method, and the method calculateERA() is correct syntax, i'm just wondering if there is a way to tell it to access the Pitcher object, because it gives me a syntax error there is no calculateERA() in the PLAYER method which there isn't it's in the pitcher method.

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the answer! You have to type cast it and you have to obey the hierarchy so in my case it would be:

> ERA+= ((Pitcher)roster[i]).calculateERA();